# React Native access to the value while animating

Tags: javascript, react-native

I feel like this is very simple to do but I've been on it for a few hours. I'm new to react and am currently working on a simple animation where it scrolls a few items. However, I'd like it to play a sound whenever the value of the animation hits a certrain treshold.

**Code**

```
const end = -4352;
Animated.timing(this.state.left, {
  toValue: end,
  easing: Easing.bezier(0.3, 1, 0.65, 1),
  duration: 6500,
  useNativeDriver: false,
}).start(() => console.log("finished scrolling"));
```

How can I make it so when the animating value hits X it does Y?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constant after how much ms (milliseconds) you want to execute something, lets say like this

```
const SOUND_START_AT = 3000 // after 3 seconds
const end = -4352;

Animated.timing(this.state.left, {
  toValue: end,
  easing: Easing.bezier(0.3, 1, 0.65, 1),
  duration: 6500,
  useNativeDriver: false,
}).start(() => setTimeout(() => {

  // this block will be executed after SOUND_START_AT seconds

}, SOUND_START_AT));
```